# How to override CSS in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm making a website using Laravel and I'm happy with the standard CSS of it in the app.css file. However for one page I'd like to change the font size. Is there a way to import both the app.css and a customized CSS, so that the latter overrides the app.css? Or is there an easier way to do this? I want to change the style of text in tables, so I thought I had to use CSS for that. It's pretty much impossible to edit the app.css file because it's minimalized and I can't understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best way is create a new css file and define it after app.css. all your overwritten code will be write in new file.

Comment: You should be editing `app.scss`, not `app.css`. If you're using layout, you could extend it with a `@stack` and on your desired page `@push` into that stack.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in public folder and call it in the view with something like

  `<link href="{{ asset('css/mystyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`. 
Make sure You put it after  `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
i use **scss** + **scoped** for this problem,

I add class **cpl-lesson** behind **template** then import css of vue in **style tag**

```
<template>
    <div class="row cpl-lesson"></div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    .cpl-lesson {
        @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
        @import url("~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css");
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a new stylesheet in `public/css/style.css`
2. Include it into your blade template just like 
   `<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}"  rel="stylesheet">`